I have brown tiny bugs all over the house
These bugs are crawling all around in my house, firstly they suddenly appeared in the kitchen after the 2-3 days of continuous rain. but then it started to move on sofa, bed, all on clothes, they move very slow and dont fly but dont know they somehow moved to worn clothes and transferred to other parts in house. and also they bites which is more irritating 
i am unable to get more pictures clearly its very small.

this is the closest pic i could manage to get clearly
i did pest control in house but there was no effect on them.
some how after few days we mopped whole house and furniture with harpic's acid based Clear after that we didn't se them for 3-4 days but again it came back.
even person who did pest control he said there is no description in their directory of this bug.. please if anyone know or faced  issues about this bug please help with the suggestion on how to terminate it.

I'm guessing you are from India based on your name. Is this also where you are in the world? ID for insects is quite regional, so a location is important. Dimensions would also help.

yes i am from Pune, Maharashtra, India. currently raining season is here.
